# This app is not verified by google even though it is verified

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using google app Oauth for authentication.
I Submitted the app and got verified.
Verification status says Published and application type set to public

But when i use it through my application it says unverified.

> This app isn't verified This app hasn't been verified by Google yet.
>   Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.

Thanks .

Comment: did you change the scopes?  If so it will need to be revrified

Comment: Nope i did not do any changes after that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem .

App is verified but when i send the request with the scope which is not added to the scopes .

Thanks guys

Comment: Where to add those scopes?

Comment: Refer :
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en
Click User consent